# Too many redirects: SSO implementation in Spring Boot using OAuth2 against Azure AD

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

In my `Java 11`, `Spring Boot 2.7.4`, `Maven` application, I am using `Spring Security`, specifically `AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, in order to authenticate my users via Azure AD Integration following a tutorial. First step was to include the following dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Next, I am overriding `AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as follows. Note the security exceptions.

```
import com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AadOAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Ordered {

    @Value("${sso.azure.ad.auth.provider.order:2}")
    private int order;

    /**
     * Add configuration logic as needed.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**","/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/oauth2/authorization/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

}
```

This code works fine in a simple proof of concept deployment. In this PoC, the service is running directly in my IDE on a personal laptop and the Azure AD is a simple test account I setup myself and some test users. The redirect URI points to localhost:

```
http://localhost:11120/login/oauth2/code/
```

However, in my production environment, the code is containerised into `Docker` images, which are deployed to a set of `AWS` `EC2` instances sitting behind a load balancer and the Azure AD instance is an official production one registered for my organisation. The redirect URI references the load balancer (note the lack of a trailing forward slash):

```
https://my-load-balancer:11120/login/oauth2/code
```

In my production deployment, browser users are first redirected to the Microsoft login screen as expected, and they are successfully able to authenticate themselves. But when the application then attempts to obtain a token, I see a repeating redirection loop in the logs, as pasted below. Note that the logs have been sanitized and the tokens replaced with `0.ARXXXXX` for brevity. I have labelled the initial request plus the first and second attempts to authenticate, after that the same pattern is seen in a loop.

```
    Original request:
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,437 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Securing GET /content/documents/myapp?test_no=I1111115432BBBBBBB&entry_number=415895J
    
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,446 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /content/documents
    /myapp?test_no=I1111115432BBBBBBB&entry_number=415895J] with attributes [authenticated]
    
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,461 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Saved request https://my-load-balancer:11120/content/
    documents/myapp?test_no=I1111115432BBBBBBB&entry_number=415895J to session
    
    First attempt to authenticate:
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,470 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Redirecting to https://my-load-balancer:11120/oauth2/authorization/azure
    
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,537 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-9] Securing GET /oauth2/authorization/azure
    
    2022-12-06 15:58:59,558 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-9] Redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ac52f73c-fd1a-4a9a-8e7a-4a248f31
    39e1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YYYYYYY&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=0jyV5HiOjxBLTG4cIs1koydlLFEPCZx_4RWuNg3wQpw%3D&redirect_uri
    =https://my-load-balancer:11120/login/oauth2/code&nonce=N-Tc2RIad5dFccOHTx79ifPhgs4UYoEnnJIJk0rApl8
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,356 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Securing GET /login/oauth2/code?code=0.ARXXXXX
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,357 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /login/oauth2/code
    ?code=0.ARXXXXX] with attributes [authenticated]
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,358 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Saved request https://my-load-balancer:11120/login/oa
    uth2/code?code=0.ARXXXXX to session
    
    Second attempt to authenticate:
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,358 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-10] Redirecting to https://my-load-balancer:11120/oauth2/authorization/azure
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,391 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-1] Securing GET /oauth2/authorization/azure
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,415 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-1] Redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ac52f73c-fd1a-4a9a-8e7a-4a248f31
    39e1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YYYYYYY&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&state=N6S7RwKvgVQjwB1oAzcdvBF0rcCVbMkemLVV4KjfaKU%3D&redirect_uri
    =https://my-load-balancer:11120/login/oauth2/code&nonce=_Bg814QoGQJv7fbzslGq2oh_MePQLPBHTp8j2wdkY0w
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,693 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-3] Securing GET /login/oauth2/code?code=0.ARXXXXX
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,694 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-3] Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /login/oauth2/code?
    code=0.ARXXXXX] with attributes [authenticated]
    
    2022-12-06 15:59:00,695 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache [https-jsse-nio-11120-exec-3] Saved request https://my-load-balancer:11120/login/oau
    th2/code?code=0.ARXXXXX to session
    
    Further attempts to authenticate follow in a loop until 'too many redirects' error is seen in browser.
```

As a first attempt to fix this issue, I added the security exceptions seen in the code example above to exempt those patterns from security, but this made no difference.

I then thought that perhaps the Docker container could not 'see' login.microsoftonline.com in order to authenticate. However, I can clearly see it in the logs and I do not see any connection exceptions or similar that I would expect to see if this were the issue.

Now, I am thinking that the issue may well be due to the fact that the redirect URI points to a load balancer rather than localhost. Regarding this, I was advised to use the following config settings, but it had no effect:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

I am now thinking that I should try setting the redirect URI to localhost rather than the load balancer and to include a trailing slash in the redirect URI. I will try this, but as I am working in a tied down production environment, it will take a few days to effect.

In the meantime, I would be very grateful for any suggestions or ideas and I thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Have you tried something like `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure`

Comment: @kavyaSaraboju Many thanks for the suggestion. I haven't tried this - would you recommend it? I have asked to switch it to https://localhost:11120/login/oauth2/code/ as this is what I have seen used in tutorials and this is what is working in my proof of concept (http not https). Should I use 'azure' at the end as per your example? One trouble is, as I am working in a tied down, heavily administered environment, any change takes a few days to effect, so I don't have the luxury of trying lots of combinations quickly unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer because we managed to get past this particular hurdle by adding to the security exceptions in our Security Config class (original code shown in the original post).

Adding two variations of `login/oauth2/code` to the exceptions, gives the full set below.

```
"/", "/home", "/login**", "/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/oauth2/authorization/**", "login/oauth2/code", "/login/oauth2/code**")
```

This fixed the `Too Many Redirects` issue. However, the next hurdle is dealing with a 404 exception, which is now occurring when attempting to access `login/oauth2/code`. For this I have asked another SO question: [Spring Boot SSO Azure AD Redirection causing 404 Error after successful authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74731727/spring-boot-sso-azure-ad-redirection-causing-404-error-after-successful-authoriz)

Many thanks!